# mysql select count of records with time gap

Tags: mysql

Trying to do a simple select count(*) on a table with a datetime column (abc_datetime).  However I want to return a count(*) for those rows where the datetime value is at least 15 minutes later than any other row's datetime value.  The idea being that I want to ignore any subsequent rows that have a datetime value within 15 minutes of the first.

```
Table Test
+---------------------+
| abc_datetime        |
+---------------------+
| 2014-07-21 00:49:52 |
| 2014-07-21 01:49:50 |
| 2014-07-21 02:49:45 |
| 2014-07-21 03:49:39 |
| 2014-07-21 04:49:38 |
| 2014-07-21 05:49:32 |
| 2014-07-21 06:49:24 |
| 2014-07-21 07:49:20 |
| 2014-07-21 08:49:14 |
| 2014-07-21 09:00:16 |
| 2014-07-21 09:00:25 |
| 2014-07-21 09:50:55 |
| 2014-07-21 09:51:03 |
| 2014-07-21 09:51:33 |
| 2014-07-21 09:51:46 |
| 2014-07-21 10:51:36 |
| 2014-07-21 11:51:30 |
| 2014-07-21 12:51:22 |
| 2014-07-21 13:51:12 |
| 2014-07-21 14:51:05 |
| 2014-07-21 15:50:55 |
+---------------------+
21 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Would like to return a count of 18 as the datetime records from 09:00:25 AND 09:51:XX would be ignored in the count as they're within 15 minutes of a previous row's datetime value.

Comment: Outer join those that ARE within 15 mins. Then filter on the nulls

Comment: (but I think it's 16)

Comment: Oops, I missed some records.  Not good with doing an outer join.

Comment: Not good? You mean in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.abc_datetime
              from test t2
              where t2.abc_datetime < t.abc_datetime
              order by t2.abc_datetime
              limit 1
             ) as prev_dt
      from test t
     ) t
where prev_dt is null or prev_dt < abc_datetime - interval 15 minute;
```

You could also do this with a `not exists`:

```
select count(*)
from test t
where not exists (select 1
                  from test t2
                  where t2.abc_datetime < t.abc_datetime and
                        t2.abc_datetime >= t.abc_datetime - interval 15 minute
                 );
```

I prefer this version for just getting the count.  The first version is better for actually seeing the values.

Comment: Thanks!  It took a little more "adjustment" on the query as the queries above ran a little over a minute each (table has over 11K rows).  I now have it under a second.